# Не получается добавить данные в Firebase в андроид-приложении

Tags: android, firebase

Только приступил к освоению сервиса Firebase и его Database, пытаюсь просто протестировать, как добавлять туда данные по нажатию кнопок (приложение делается на основе Google Maps API). Само облако, если верить андроид студии, подключилось нормально, по крайней мере работает аутентификация пользователей через email (пользователи добавляются). В правилах базы данных прописал, что писать туда можно и без аутентификации.
Код простой:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();//Эту строку добавлял и в метод onCreate, и в onMapReady, где это сделать правильно?

mDatabase.child("User").setValue("Ku-ku");//Эта строка в методе onCkick соответствующей кнопки.
```

Что я делаю не так?

**UPD:**
В логах обнаружил такие записи:
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/User failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

gradle следующий:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Сама база абсолютно пустая

**UPD2**

Все, разобрался, прошу прощения за беспокойство! Оказывается, у меня был залогинен пользователь, а в правилах стояло, что в базу можно писать без логина. Теперь все в норме.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас структура бд немного не такая и что-то пропущено. В общем покажите есть ли чего в БД

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз, плиз, добавил информацию.

Comment: Все, разобрался, прошу прощения за беспокойство! Оказывается, у меня был залогинен пользователь, а в правилах стояло, что в базу можно писать без логина. Теперь все в норме.

Answer (score 2):

Для более детального ответа желательно добавлять скриншот или JSON структуру базы данных. По-моему, у вас в `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` лишняя команда `getReference();`
Она, насколько я помню, начинает работу с корневым каталогом внутри базы данных. Здесь же вы указываете пустой параметр, то есть переключение идет в никуда. Попробуйте этот код:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase.getReference("hello").setValue("world");
```

В этом случае в корне БД создастся ключ hello со значением world
Можно поступить и иначе:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    mDatabase.child("User").setValue("Ku-ku");
```

Здесь же создается в корне каталог Users, в котором лежит User со значением Ku-ku
Инициализировать работу с базой данных рекомендую тогда, когда нужно к ней обратиться, но можно и просто прописать `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();` в `onCreate` и работать не заморачиваясь.

Comment: Внимательно просмотрел логи, обнаружил такие записи: W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/User failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied  и  W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. Правила стоят такие: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }

Comment: Смею предположить, что у Вас проблема с google-services.json Проверьте правильность подключения firebase к приложению или попробуйте подключить его вручную. Как это сделать написано здесь https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, что в Rules для базы данных Firebase у вас стоит условие только для авторизированых пользователей. Попробуйте в Firebase Console изменить правила записи и чтения RealtimeDatabase[image: Databse Rules]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null || auth == null",
    ".write": "auth != null || auth == null"
  }
}
```